# Migrating a database table with timestamp columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in the process of migrating a SQL 2008 R2 database between software versions (6 years old to current schema.) There are a few auditing tables with SQL TimeStamp columns on them. Am doing this by copying data out of original tables into the new structure - the change is fairly complex as you might expect after 6 years.

Is there a way to preserve the fingerprint of the timestamps as I move it into a new database or a best practise way of keeping the audit traceability of this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to `varbinary(8)` to preserve it:

```
select  cast([timestamp] as varbinary(8))
```

But the value of `timestamp` itself is not particularly useful: it does not translate to a particular time.  In the future, MSDN suggests it might be renamed to the more appropriate `rowversion`.

Comment: Thanks; no way to keep the value when you migrate sadly which is a bit frustrating - mind you no idea why the original guys decided to use a timestamp in the first place.

Comment: A "timestamp" value can provide an audit trail showing when the action actually happened.  If there are legal and/or service requirements associated with the time an action happened, I would suggest saving the original database in a format which can be examined in the future, then flagging records with a "migrated" flag so that the timestamp is understood to be the time of the migration, not the original transaction time.

Comment: @JulieinAustin: But a timestamp does not represent an actual time.  You can't look at it and say, "this row was last written on May 19th".

Answer (score 0):

I have used SQL 2014 and it allows rowversion, for your case, you have to convert the timestamp ie. to varbinary and save in another table for reference in future. Timestamp is a read only column.